# Single VBA query for multiple tables data

Tags: sql, vba

I have stocks data in 7 tables, tblStock, tblIn1, tblIn2, tblIn3, tblOut1, tblOut2, tblOut3. I have to get sum of quantity and amount from each table for each stock item to manipulate in different ways. How can I get these values through vba query at single place? I tried but failed. Can anybody guide me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine data from multiple data sources using a **Union** query, as long as the source tables and/or queries are set up similarly.

---

## The SQL UNION Operator

[image: img]The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more `SELECT` statements.

- Each `SELECT` statement within `UNION` must have the **same number of columns**
- The columns must also have **similar data types**
- The columns in each `SELECT` statement must also be in the **same order**

### UNION Syntax

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

### UNION ALL Syntax

The `UNION` operator selects only **distinct values** by default. To allow duplicate values, use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

**Note:** The column names in the result-set are usually **equal to the column names in the first `SELECT` statement** in the `UNION`.

[image: img]

---

### Sources and more info:

- Office.com : [Use a union query to combine multiple queries into a single result](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-1f772ec0-cc73-474d-ab10-ad0a75541c6e)
- W3Schools : [SQL UNION Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)
- YouTube : [Microsoft Access - Creating a Union Query](https://youtu.be/-tUMfbsJVTA)
- DoFactory : [SQL UNION Clause Examples](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/union)

Comment: Nicely eplained how to `UNION`, but if  the In/Out tables would be merged into one table with additional fields for number and type (In/Out), a simple `WHERE`filter would be enough and way faster.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; Are you suggesting a `WHERE` with a bunch of `JOIN`s on the OP's tables?

Comment: The `tblStok`and a `tblInOut`where the 6 original tables /tblIn1, ..., tblOut3) are merged (with the UNION) in one table, with additional fields for typeInOut (values In or Out) and a field for the number of the original tblInX / tblOutY.. tblStock is join witg this. For the whole som, you filter on iype and aggregate `Sum` If you need the old structr, you create a query with filter on typa and number , what gives the starting data.

Comment: Just an educated guess ;) Every time I see descriptive tablenames with trailing numbers I am on alert. Additional he wants to union them, so fields should be very similar. I assume the numbers are locations and In/Out is stock increase/decrease. I am not sur about `tblStocks`, the products? or the stored computed In/Outs?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher carefu! ...you know [what they say](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Belson#Career) about assumptions!

Comment: Link showed too late ;) Can't agree on this in comments, but in traffic ;)

Comment: Your interpretation is more accurate.  The other one bugs me, but people say it all the time around here.  I never knew the source until just now.  (By the way yo can edit comments too, for up to 5 minutes - hence the link showing late, it was an afterthought!)

Comment: I know the limit and ran into it too offten :( Also I ,missed the pun as a not native english speaker. After recognizing, it' fit perfect for type-writers but mine is closer to reallity:)